# Revert from MIUI to Motoblur

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.3-gingerbread, motorola-defy, motoblur, miui

I am a proud owner of Motorola Defy. A few months ago I upgraded my defy from 2.1 to 2.2. Although it had new features it became a bit laggy and so finally I decided to root my defy and install MIUI Gingerbread.

I was using MIUI Gingerbread all this time and suddenly it started itching me and a thought came to my mind that I want to experience Motoblur again.

I had already created an image of my Motoblur Froyo before installing MIUI Gingerbread. So I went ahead and reverted the Froyo image back on my defy.

But then some of the things stopped working: e.g. Camera is not working now.

I found that the Foryo image did not copy the Motoblur Froyo Kernel and when I reverted back my defy is still having the MIUI kernel.

Can someone help me getting back to Motoblur Froyo or can I download the original kernel and re-install it back to my defy?

Anything would help....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this tool called `RSD Lite`, which is (AFAIK) an internal tool from motorola to flash their phones. You should be able to find it around the googles.

And [here](http://modmymobile.com/forums/637-motorola-defy-general/557901-defy-firmwares-superthread.html) you should be able to pick up a stock firmware for the Defy.

This method worked for my Moto Cliq XT, but don't let this be a  guarantee for your Defy!

Comment: thanks a lot buddy...i will try and will let you know if it works..thanks again